# Real embedding of the splitting field of $X^3-2$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Does the splitting field of $X^3-2$ have a real embedding?

Comment: How could it have?

Comment: Note that if $x \ne y$ are two distinct roots of $X^3-2$, and $t = \frac{x}{y}$, then $t^3 = \frac{2}{2} = 1$ and $t \ne 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Briefly, because in $\mathbb C$, it has $3$ distinct roots, so the splitting field contains these, but in $\mathbb R$ there is only one root (say, because of strict monotonicity of $x\mapsto x^3$), so no *embedding* can be possible, as all $3$ roots should still satisfy the polynomial, hence would go into the same element, $\sqrt[3]2$.